# Flutter web not redirecting to server-side endpoint

Tags: flutter, http-post, dart-html, http-status-code-303

I have created an endpoint in my server that has a status code of 303 and redirects to a prebuilt stripe checkout page. Though, when I post to this endpoint using this [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http), my flutter app does not redirect to the checkout page. Instead it responds with a get request to the redirect location header with a status code of 200. The checkout page is never redirected to.

```
response = await http.post(Uri.parse('myURL'));
```

Trying to stop the post request from responding with a get request, I tried to catch the location header and redirect to it using this [url-launcher package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). But this throws an error because it is still redirecting to a get request of the checkout page link and there is not a location header.

```
      http.Request request = http.Request("post", Uri.parse('myURL'))..followRedirects=false..maxRedirects=0;
      http.Client baseClient = http.Client();
      http.StreamedResponse response = await baseClient.send(request);
      Uri redirectUri = Uri.parse(response.headers['location']!);
      if (!await launchUrl(redirectUri, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
        throw 'Could not launch $redirectUri';
      }
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to have my flutter app redirect to the status code 303 location header link, I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Is your server endpoint following the PRG pattern? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Yes @activout.se

Comment: can you see that in the server logs that it actually sends the Location header?

Comment: Yes, the post request has a location header and then a get request is made automatically with a request URL that is the same as the location header of the post request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never figured out how to get Flutter to redirect to a new page from a post request, but I came up with a different solution. Using the 'dart:html' package, I was able to use its window redirect option with a url. In my api I returned the url I wanted to redirect to through the body.

```
String redirectUri = response.body;
html.window.open(redirectUri, "_self");
```